# Set gateway variable in process

Tags: gateway, processmaker

Goodnight!

How to set the variable to direct a route from a gateway?

Form:
[image]

Process gateway:
[image]

---

I deleted the sequence flow line and remade it. When creating it first, in the same way, the validation expression worked.
Is this behavior correct?
Shouldn't the validation expression work regardless of the order of creation of the sequence flow line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the correct way to set condition. It doesn't matter in which order you create the sequence as long as the conditions you specified are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the condition test is only working if it is the first line of the sequence flow created in some cases.

At another gateway I was unable to proceed as above.

For some reason, even the sequence flow with a label appears as if it doesn't have: "Gateway: Label Undefined": [Process view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tblt7.png)

Sequence flow: [Sequence flow config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KDwd.png)

Another way: [Another way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c2Fr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: When changing a validation expression you need to create a new instance of the process for it to take effect!

Answer (score 0):

The way you set the condition in the arrow is correct. Please use the validation if necessary, this may help to understand the problem when setting the process. There is not order to set the route, the important thing is to have a well configured flow as you show in the image.